# How to insert string var into JSON?

Tags: json, node.js

I'm starting out in Node and am hitting an API. I am trying to take a String variable that will be used in place of a JSON parameter.

Let me start with the code as it will make more sense

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/api/scan',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
};

// Set up the request
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
});
res.on('end', function () {
    body = JSON.parse(body)
    // Make sure it's working
    console.log(body.response.subject);
});
});

// post the data
var url = 'ssl.com';
post_req.write('{"url": ' + url + ', "path":"/", "port":"443", "live_scan":"false", "advanced":"true"}');
post_req.end();
```

If you look at the last three lines, I am trying to set a url into a string var `url` and then insert it into the JSON.

This is the error I get:

```
$ node example.js
undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.parse (native)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\projects\ssl-scanner\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:88:17)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\projects\ssl-scanner\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\projects\ssl-scanner\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\projects\ssl-scanner\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\projects\ssl-scanner\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:308:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:80:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:377:13)
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\projects\node\example.js:23:21)
at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:377:13)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
```

Now the reason I'm doing this is because I want to eventually loop through a text file that contains a list of URLs (One on each line as the delimiter would be the new line) and set `url` equal to each url in the list and then send the request.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome

-Hamza

Comment: Looks like the result of your request is in html instead of JSON.

Comment: don't create json by hand.... there's a built-in method for that. Your current way would create invalid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're not getting a JSON response from the API, but a HTML code; a possible issue could be that you're not passing a proper JSON string in your request.

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var data = {
  'url': url,
  'path': '/',
  'port': 443,
  'live_scan': false,
  'advanced': true
};

post_req.write( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Also, check what the `Content-Type` header is set to, in the response you get, before attempting to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: This was perfect. I decided to move the JSON that i was passing, into it's own var:  

`var url = 'ssl.com';`  
 `var catURL = {"url": url, "path":"/", "port":"443", "live_scan":"false", "advanced":"true"};`  
`post_req.write(JSON.stringify(catURL));`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the backtrace the error gives you, the problem is line 23.

at IncomingMessage. **(C:\projects\node\example.js:23:21)**

That line is:

```
body = JSON.parse(body)
```

I assume that what you're opening isn't actually JSON, so when you try to do JSON.parse on it, it fails. Seeing as how the error also said:

```
Unexpected token s<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

We can be pretty confident that your body isn't JSON.

Just try logging the body, and see what it is.

Comment: Using this: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it looks like it's not valid JSON

Comment: Specifically, you have actual newlines in your strings causing errors. As with any String, you cannot start on a new line in the middle of a string then close the string on the next line. Your example is split up on about 15 lines. I deleted the new lines and got the entire JSON on one line and it's valid, and should now work with your example: http://pastebin.com/FsDSMkaF

Comment: Is this something on my end? I thought this is just the response i'm getting from the server?